# How to determine which IP address is in use after accept?

Tags: c++, c

If I wrote a server bound to a wildcard address (`INADDR_ANY`), how to determine which IP address the client is connected to?

I tried the following code when the after a successful accept call, but it just returned 0.0.0.0.

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &server_address.sin_addr, s, sizeof(s));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine IP used by client connecting to INADDR_ANY listener socket in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047704/how-to-determine-ip-used-by-client-connecting-to-inaddr-any-listener-socket-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [How to determine IP used by client connecting to INADDR_ANY listener socket in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3047704/172695), use [getsockname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/getsockname.html), which gives you the socket which the connection is bound to (on local level).

This is for C, but is applicable for C++ to.

Answer (score 0):

the accept system call will have a address of type struct sockaddr_in or struct sockaddr_in6.

the client address will be stored there.

you can get it using inet_ntoa, or inet_ntop.